# How to upgrade 4.5 version WCF project to .NET 6

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, upgrade, .net-6.0

I am upgrading my .NET solution from 4.5 to 6.0. I have multiple projects in one solution. One  project which has domain classes is upgraded to 6.0 which is consuming WCF services which is another project. WCF service project is still in 4.5 version. I am not able to figure it out, how will I upgrade WCF project to 6.0. Or another way I could think of is, can I call WCF service which is in 4.5 from model project which is in 6.0. Is upward compatibility possible in .NET.
Any guidance/ alternate approach would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: WCF is only supported on the client side in .NET6.0. The server classes have been deprecated. There are some github projects to replace that, but which one(s) are appropriate for you depends on your use case.

Comment: Basically, [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF) is the only option. However, note that it is not trivial to migrate. The hosting story has changed (CoreWCF runs on top of Kestrel, not .NET FX WCF's ServiceHost). It might sound like truism, but the better seperated your service logic (and model) is from WCF the easier it will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can add references to external services using the **WCF Web Service Reference Provider tool**(.NET Core projects, including .NET 5 and later), see the following documentation for specific steps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2022#to-add-a-reference-to-an-external-service-net-core-projects-including-net-5-and-later

Regarding updates, you can choose alternatives to wcf: [gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-6.0), [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF), and [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
https://visualrecode.com/blog/wcf-alternatives-for-net5/

- If you are looking for a flexible framework, the target gRPC gRPC is
  already used in many cross-platform applications and multiple
  frameworks. gRPC will give you the most flexibility.
- If your application primarily interacts with the browser, target
  ASP.NET Core MVC. It has some disadvantages compared to gRPC, but it
  is easier to use for web applications.
- If you absolutely can't move on from WCF, watch CoreWCF. The .NET
  Framework isn't going away anytime soon, and WCF will continue to
  function. If it's important to have it early, you might consider
  becoming a contributor to the project itself.

Comment: applies to use net5-6-7 to ***call WCF/SOAP service***?